# some missing messages in ZeroMQ multiple topic filtering usage

Tags: java, zeromq, jeromq

I have a ZeroMQ subscriber application written in Java using JeroMQ 0.5.2.
In the code, I subscribe to multiple topics like that:

```
Socket subscriber = context.createSocket(SocketType.SUB);
subscriber.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:2770");
subscriber.subscribe("DAX");
subscriber.subscribe("AD");
```

I see the messages starting with DAX and AD when I run my subscriber but it seems that some messages are missing in multiple filter case because when I subscribe to only DAX or only AD, I see tons of update messages. When I subscribe to both topics I see little of them for DAX, most of the update messages are missing.

Is there something wrong with my snippet?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"Is there something wrong with my snippet?"*

No, there is not.

> <sub>The rest of the claimed observations is not reproducible, the less explainable without seeing the logs, the complete SUB-side setup + algorithmisation and the PUB-side broadcast data formatting ( if not the complete MCVE / MRE ).</sub>